# See what a previously purchased app costs on iOS App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

How can I on the iOS App Store see what an app that I've already bought costs at the moment?

Comment: Wonder why someone down voted? this is actually a great question.  As far as I can tell, it hasn't been asked before, and without logging into iTunes differently on the store, there doesn't appear to be a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browse to the app within the iOS app store. Click the 3 dots [edit: for newer versions of iOS, the Send/Share button (box with uparrow)], and select 'Gift app..." you will see the current price displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was available back when the question was originally asked, but this is the best way to do it now.

Answer (score 12):

If you're looking for the current price (*which might not be the price you paid*), you can Google search for the product and Google will display the App Store price in the results:

[image: Search screenshot]

Comment: Not the greatest method... Hoping someone else has something better!

Comment: Hey, why no freehand? :)

Comment: You can also add site:itunes.apple.com to narrow down the search results.

Answer (score 9):

You could use an app like [AppShopper](https://itunes.apple.com/app/appshopper-social/id602522782), which shows the current price of an app as well as past price changes. AppShopper also has a website where you can find the same information, for example for GarageBand: http://appshopper.com/music/garageband (you can change the country/currency at the bottom right of the page, past price changes are shown in the “app activity” box).

Answer (score 4):

The only way to know the price from the Store requires that the specific app is not installed on your device, and not being *signed in*. Details:

If the app you want to know the price about **is not** installed on your device, then:

- Open the App Store app. The app opens with **featured** section highlighted.
- Go to the bottom of the list in that section.
- Tap on your Apple id.
- Tap on **sign out**.
- Force-close the app (the App Store app) i.e. open the multitask pane and swipe the app out of the screen.
- Open the App Store app again.
- Look for your app and you will see its price.

If the app is installed on the device, you could delete it and follow the above process.

If you wouldn't like to uninstall (and possibly install again), then the best option is watching the result from googling **itunes *appname***, where appname is the (approximate) name of the app.

Answer (score 3):

As I known, there is no way to see on App Store directly. 
Usually you will get a receipt deleveried via email after buying an App, in which you can see the price at that moment.